# avr microcontrollers and how to get started coding init or main loop or timers or interrupts

Tags: avr, pic

I have been modifying AVR and PIC microcontroller code for a few years now for work but have never written anything from scratch, I understand it pretty well.

I am starting to write my own code now and am having trouble getting started. I was wondering how other people start writing code and if there is a book or tutorial people would recommend on this.

Do you start with coding your initialization function then interrupts then timers then the main while(1) loop... I am wondering what the best way to get started is.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

1. The first thing one does in any microcontroller project is blink an LED; keep it blinking and give it a name *("Blinky")*, too. It's the ***heart beat*** of your widget, and will always work so long as your program doesn't get stuck.
2. Commit to the local version control repository.
3. Next is to fly through the entire program in pseudo/crapcode, based on your program flow diagrams or whatever planning methods you've subscribed to. If something doesn't work or you just don't like it, comment it out but keep it there so you know to fix it later. If you don't know how to do something, write down what it's supposed to do in comments.
4. Commit to the local version control repository.
5. Time to fill in the blanks! Implement one function at a time, for example the timer, *and test it*. Your program should always compile and work as expected. I like to implement any user interface connections at this point, like UART -> RS232 -> PC links or LCD displays. Don't forget about *Blinky*.
6. Commit to the local version control repository.
7. Try to break your code with rigorous test routines; debug. [Have others review your code](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review); debug. Run your widget through its design parameters regularly, like temperature variations; debug.
8. Commit to the local version control repository.
9. Disconnect *Blinky* if you're a heartless fool, and ship.

[AVRFreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/) has an excellent tutorial written by Dean Camera (aka. [abcminuser](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=profile&mode=viewprofile&u=55749)) called **[Modularizing C Code: Managing large projects](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=48535)**. You may also be interested in reading [State Machines for Microprocessors](http://www.proaxis.com/~wagnerj/StateMachines/State%20Machines%20for%20Microprocessors.pdf) by James Wagner.

Comment: Absolutely agree about source control. Commit early, commit often

Comment: Along with the commit, is to check it out to a fresh directory and rebuild it.  Nothing worse than forgetting to add a file to the source control.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite AVR-from-scratch-in-C tutorial is https://www.mainframe.cx/~ckuethe/avr-c-tutorial/

Everyone has their own style for small embedded systems. Here's mine:

I like to use lots of C files, with the name of each making up a prefix for functions. For example, `led_init()` and `led_tick()` are both in `led.c`. This keeps things modular and helps with portability.

I use a `common.h` header file to define types, but individual includes for each module.

I tend to use a single freerunning system timer (in a `systime.c`) then have modules call out to a `systime_get()` function to fetch the current time in system ticks or milliseconds. Each module can then schedule events through software timers using the `X_tick()` functions.

**common.h:**

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include <stdio.h>  // general purpose headers
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
...
#endif
```

**uart.h:**

```
#ifndef UART_H
#define UART_H
#include <avr/usart.h>  // microcontroller specific headers for uart
...

void uart_init(void);
void uart_putc(uint8_t ch);
...

#endif
```

**uart.c:**

```
#include "common.h"
#include "uart.h"

void uart_isr(void) __interrupt VECTOR
{
  // handle incoming data
}

void uart_init(void)
{
  // setup hardware
}

void uart_putc(uint8_t ch)
{
  UART_TX_FIFO_REGISTER = ch;
  while(!TX_COMPLETE_REGISTER);
}
```

**led.h:**

```
#ifndef LED_H
#define LED_H
#include <avr/ioports.h>  // microcontroller specific headers for port io
...

#define LED_DDR   PORTAD
#define LED_PIN   5
#define LED_MASK  (1 << LED_PIN)
#define LED_PORT  PORTA

void led_init(void);
void led_set(void);
void led_tick(void);
...

#endif
```

**led.c:**

```
#include "common.h"
#include "led.h"

void led_init(void)
{
  LED_DDR |= LED_MASK;
}

void led_set(void)
{
  LED_PORT |= LED_MASK;
}

void led_tick(void)
{
  // animate LEDs in an amusing fashion
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "common.h"
#include "led.h"
#include "uart.h"

int main(void)
{
  led_init();
  uart_init();
  ...

  led_set();

  while(1)
  {
    led_tick();
    uart_tick();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here are two "real world" projects using this style for [AVR](http://blog.hodgepig.org/busninja/) and [MSP430](http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/10/575/).